# Is there a specific word for this kind of re-sealable plastic seal?

Tags: single-word-requests

You know those re-sealable plastic bags, where the seal is one plastic strip that you squeeze between two other, parallel plastic strips on the other surface? Like on a Ziploc™ bag, only without the zip?

Is there a common word or phrase used to describe those seals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The US Transportation Security Administration (TSA) officially refers to it as a [zip-top bag](http://www.tsa.gov/311/). I have never heard or read this usage elsewhere, and I imagine it was probably constructed to avoid the genericized trademark *Ziploc*.

In the southeastern US, a resealable plastic bag is usually called a *ziplock bag*, regardless of whether it has a zipper or not. This is likely true for elsewhere around the US but I can't vouch for that.

Oddly enough, [this Web site](http://www.cockeyed.com/science/eyeclops/eyeclops_ziplock.shtml) features macro-images of the bags and several identifying buzzwords, including *slider seal*, *closures*, *channel*, and *double zipper seal*.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is the most complete answer, and I enjoyed the odd microscope website :)

Comment: In the southeastern US, they don't seem to understand what a trademark is. Every soda is a Coke there too.

Answer (score 1):

These are usually called "Press Seal" or "Press-Seal" or "Press-N-Seal" or "Press 'n' Seal" bags. Google "press seal" and look at all the references.

Answer (score 1):

Resealable seems to be the British English word and the words Robusto said are American English. Supermarkets say resealable (if anything), such as [Tesco's bags.](http://www.tesco.com/groceries/Product/Details/?id=252366394)

Answer (score 0):

i just had a search on ebay for zip lock bags and it seems the UK equivalent and proper nomenclature is 'GRIP SEAL BAGS' for the exact type of seal you're talking about.

Comment: Please add some support to your answer. This site tries to compile well-researched answers. Your answer will probably get deleted if you don't. Please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour)